# React Query Auto Sync TextArea doesn't sync current state in sibling component unless window is switched?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-query

I have a Writing Pad where I write on the right (**Writer.tsx**) & create docs on the left (**DocsList.tsx**)

These two are both sibling components.

When I write on the writing pad (**Writer**), it syncs state with the server properly but I don't see it reflected in the left side (**DocsList**) unless I switch windows which causes refetch & loads appropriately.

See the image below, right side (`This doesn't work`) is mismatched with the left side (`hello world` which was previously written in place of `This doesn't work`).

[image: writing pad image]

I am using GraphQL Codegen to generate React Query Hooks.

##### DocsList.tsx

```
import clsx from 'clsx'
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import { useQueryClient } from 'react-query'
import { useSnapshot } from 'valtio'

import { useCreateDocsMutation } from '../graphql/createDocs.generated'
import { useDeleteDocsByIdMutation } from '../graphql/deleteDocsById.generated'
import { useGetDocsQuery } from '../graphql/getDocs.generated'
import { state } from '../store/index'

export const DocsList = () => {
  const snap = useSnapshot(state)
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const { data } = useGetDocsQuery()
  const { mutate } = useCreateDocsMutation({
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      const queryKey = 'GetDocs'
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(queryKey)

      if (data.createDocs?.id) {
        state.docs.id = data.createDocs.id
      }
    },
  })
  const { mutate: deleteDocs } = useDeleteDocsByIdMutation({
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      const queryKey = 'GetDocs'
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(queryKey)
    },
  })

  const docs = data?.docs

  const createNewDocs = () => {
    mutate({})
  }

  const getDocsById = (id: string) => {
    state.docs.id = id
    if (docs) {
      for (let el of docs) {
        if (el?.id === id) {
          state.docs.text = el.text
        }
      }
    }
  }

  const deleteDocsById = (id: string) => {
    /**
     * doesn't work yet
     */
    if (docs) {
      if (docs.length === 1) {
        state.setDocs({ id: '', text: '' })
      }
      for (let i = 0; i < docs.length; i++) {
        const current = docs[i]
        let prev
        if (i !== 0) {
          prev = docs[i - 1]
        }
        if (current?.id === id && prev?.id && prev?.text) {
          state.setDocs({ id: prev.id, text: prev.text })
        }
      }
    }
    deleteDocs({ id })
  }

  return (
    <div className="mt-2 border-2 border-gray-900">
      <button
        type="button"
        className="inline-flex items-center w-full h-12 px-3 mt-0 text-sm font-medium leading-4 border-b-2 border-gray-900 shadow-sm dark:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none hover:text-white hover:bg-gray-700"
        onClick={createNewDocs}
      >
        New Docs
      </button>
      {docs?.map((doc) => {
        if (!doc?.id) return null

        return (
          <button
            key={doc.id}
            type="button"
            className={clsx(
              'inline-flex items-center w-full h-12 px-3 mt-0 text-sm font-medium leading-4 shadow-sm dark:text-gray-700 border-primary-light focus:outline-none group',
              {
                'dark:bg-primary-dark border-l-8 border-yellow-400':
                  snap.docs.id === doc.id,
                'dark:text-gray-300 dark:hover:bg-primary-darker':
                  snap.docs.id !== doc.id,
              }
            )}
            onClick={() => getDocsById(doc.id)}
          >
            <span className="truncate">{doc?.text || 'Empty docs...'}</span>
            <span
              role="button"
              className="ml-auto"
              onClick={() => deleteDocsById(doc.id)}
            >
              ❌
            </span>
          </button>
        )
      })}
    </div>
  )
}
```

The **Writer** component works well individually.

##### Writer.tsx

```
import { useQueryClient } from 'react-query'
import { useSnapshot } from 'valtio'
import { useReactQueryAutoSync } from 'use-react-query-auto-sync'

import {
  UpdateDocsMutationVariables,
  UpdateDocsDocument,
  UpdateDocsMutation,
} from '../graphql/updateDocs.generated'
import {
  GetDocsByIdDocument,
  GetDocsByIdQuery,
  GetDocsByIdQueryVariables,
} from '../graphql/getDocsById.generated'
import { useCreateDocsMutation } from '../graphql/createDocs.generated'
import { state, Docs } from '../store/index'

function fetcher<TData, TVariables>(query: string, variables?: TVariables) {
  return async (): Promise<TData> => {
    const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api', {
      method: 'POST',
      ...{
        headers: { credentials: 'include', 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables }),
    })
    const json = await res.json()

    if (json.errors) {
      const { message } = json.errors[0]
      throw new Error(message)
    }
    return json.data
  }
}

const useWritingPad = (id: string) => {
  return useReactQueryAutoSync({
    queryOptions: {
      queryKey: ['GetDocsById', { id }],
      queryFn: fetcher<GetDocsByIdQuery, GetDocsByIdQueryVariables>(
        GetDocsByIdDocument,
        { id }
      ),
    },
    mutationOptions: {
      mutationFn: (variables?: UpdateDocsMutationVariables) =>
        fetcher<UpdateDocsMutation, UpdateDocsMutationVariables>(
          UpdateDocsDocument,
          variables
        )(),
    },
    autoSaveOptions: { wait: 1000 },
    alertIfUnsavedChanges: true,
  })
}

export const Writer = () => {
  const snap = useSnapshot(state)
  const queryClient = useQueryClient()
  const { mutate } = useCreateDocsMutation({
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      const queryKey = 'GetDocs'
      queryClient.invalidateQueries(queryKey)

      if (data.createDocs?.id) {
        console.log(data.createDocs)
        state.docs.id = data.createDocs?.id
        state.docs.text = data.createDocs?.text
      }
    },
  })

  const { draft, setDraft, queryResult } = useWritingPad(snap.docs.id)

  const onThreadChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement>) => {
    const docs: Docs = {
      id: snap.docs.id,
      text: e.target.value,
    }
    state.docs = docs
    setDraft(docs)
  }

  const onClickHandler = () => {
    if (state.docs.id === '') {
      mutate({})
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <span className="absolute font-sans font-bold text-indigo-400 top-7 right-20">
        {queryResult.data?.text === draft?.text ? 'Saved!' : 'Saving...'}
      </span>
      <textarea
        className="border-2 border-gray-500 mx-20 mt-2 font-medium text-lg p-2 z-10 flex-1 h-[90vh] w-[90%] overflow-y-scroll text-gray-900 bg-transparent shadow-none outline-none resize-none focus:ring-0"
        value={draft?.text}
        onChange={onThreadChange}
        onClick={onClickHandler}
        placeholder="Write your thread here..."
        spellCheck={false}
      ></textarea>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I am using https://github.com/lukesmurray/react-query-autosync to sync the writing pad to the server with SQLite as a database using Prisma.

And I also have a [Valtio store](https://github.com/pmndrs/valtio) to keep the local state.

##### store.ts

```
import { proxy } from 'valtio'

export type Docs = {
  id: string
  text: string
}

export interface IDocsStore {
  docs: Docs
}

class DocsStore implements IDocsStore {
  docs: Docs = {
    id: '',
    text: '',
  }

  setDocs = (docs: Docs) => {
    this.docs = docs
  }
}

export const state = proxy(new DocsStore())

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  import('valtio/utils').then((utils) => {
    const { devtools } = utils
    devtools(state, 'docs')
  })
}
```

The problem I have is when I click on the right side, it doesn't show the appropriate value in `textarea`.

If I just use `valtio` store, I can easily do it but in combination with `use-react-query-auto-sync`, it doesn't update appropriately even thought the api gets called properly inside function `getDocsById`.

I'm also unable to delete properly & update the UI state. The delete mutation is performed appropriately but the UI state doesn't reflect that. I don't know how to perform Optimistic UI on `docs` so that the yellow border shows appropriately. I even read the docs.

Ideally, I want the yellow border to show on the previous item if the current one is deleted. If anything other than the current item is deleted, then it should keep the yellow border on the current item only.

The problem is maintaining 2 states: UI State (**valtio**) & Server State (**react-query**) & keeping them in sync.

How do I solve these 2 problems?

1st problem is selecting on the left & displaying the appropriate value on the writing pad textarea.

2nd problem is deleting item & selecting the previous item if current item is deleted otherwise keeping it as it is.

I've can do it with just `valtio` but adding server state is making me a bit confused.

I've made a complete minimal reproduction → https://github.com/deadcoder0904/docs-autosync/

Comment: Can you share, components where both components are consumed?

Comment: @RahulSharma what do you mean? if u mean where both `Writer.tsx` & `DocsList.tsx` are in, then they are in [index.tsx](https://github.com/deadcoder0904/docs-autosync/blob/main/pages/index.tsx). the entire reproduction is at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/docs-autosync/